# Error while call to function EVP_DigestSignFinal

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, ecdsa, openssl-engine

I'm trying to implement ECDSA with custome engine and  I'm facing error at this line EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, sig, slen)).Can anyone please guide me.

**Engine part** -->

```
EVP_PKEY_meth_set_sign(dasync_ec, dasync_ec_signinit,
           dasync_ec_sign);

static int dasync_ec_sign(EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *sig, size_t *siglen, const unsigned char *tbs, size_t tbslen)
{
    static int (*psign)(EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *sig, size_t *siglen, const unsigned char *tbs, size_t tbslen);
    if (psign == NULL)
        EVP_PKEY_meth_get_sign(dasync_ec_orig, NULL, &psign);    
    return psign(ctx,sig,siglen,tbs,tbslen);
}
```

**Tester side** -->

```
 EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx=NULL;
 EVP_PKEY *pkey =  EVP_PKEY_new(); 
 EC_KEY *eckey=NULL;
 eckey=EC_KEY_new();
 size_t *slen;
 EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(pkey,eckey);

if(!(mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create())) 
   goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignInit(mdctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), my_engine, pkey)) 
   goto err; 
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignUpdate(mdctx, msg, strlen(msg))) 
   goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, NULL, slen)) 
   goto err;
if(!(*sig = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (*slen)))) 
   goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, sig, slen)) 
 goto err;
```

Comment: This could be caused by a wide variety of reasons. Is there anything helpful in the OpenSSL error queue?

Comment: I have register this function EVP_PKEY_meth_set_sign in the engine. It's calling to the respective function. And error occurred  when it's calling to EVP_PKEY_meth_get_sign function. Can you please suggest how to tackle this.

Comment: You need to provide much more information about what you are trying to do. Please paste the code in your comment above into the actual question so it is readable. It sounds from your comment that the problem you are actually encountering is in your Engine implementation itself - is that correct? Clearly if your engine implementation fails then EVP_DigestSignFinal is also going to fail!!

Comment: Can you please guide me. regarding registration process. Which function out of these two I should have implement EVP_PKEY_meth_set_sign or EVP_PKEY_meth_set_digestsign ? how to tackle this issue ? (please refer  above code)

Answer (score 0):

What i see is that from test program you would need to replace your custom sign method via EVP Ctx calls.

```
static void set_custom_pkey_method_ec()
{
    /* Define a new EVP PKEY METHODS openssl style */
    EVP_PKEY_METHOD *orig_meth, *new_meth;
        
    /* Get openssl default EVP PKEY Method */
    orig_meth = (EVP_PKEY_METHOD *)EVP_PKEY_meth_find(EVP_PKEY_EC);
    EVP_PKEY_meth_get_sign(orig_meth, &orig_pkey_ec_sign_init, &orig_pkey_ec_sign);

    /* create a EVP PKEY method  and replace default method with our method */
    new_meth = EVP_PKEY_meth_new(EVP_PKEY_EC, EVP_PKEY_FLAG_AUTOARGLEN);
    EVP_PKEY_meth_copy(new_meth, orig_meth);
    EVP_PKEY_meth_set_sign(new_meth, orig_pkey_ec_sign_init, custom_pkey_ec_sign);

    /* Add our custom signing method */
    EVP_PKEY_meth_add0(new_meth);
    return;
}
```

Your Test program should be modified as below

```
EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx=NULL;
EVP_PKEY *pkey =  EVP_PKEY_new(); 
EC_KEY *eckey=NULL;
eckey=EC_KEY_new();
size_t *slen;
EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(pkey,eckey);

**set_custom_pkey_method_ec();**

EVP_Digist_Init();
```